# Setear un atributo de la base de datos a un input

Tags: javascript, laravel

Tengo una funcion prueba en javascript y lo que hace es que cuando seleccione un desarrollador en el select pase el nombre de este a un input , pero me pasa el id (todos los campos del select son de la base de datos) me podrian ayudar a solucionarlo? Solo necesito el nombre del desarrollador en el input

```
<script>
 function prueba(x) 
 {

    var opcion=document.getElementById('inputdesa').value=x;
 }
 </script>



<div class="form-group">
<label for="">Desarrollador</label>
    <select name="id_calcu" id="inputid_calcu" class="form-control" onchange="prueba(this.value);">

   @foreach($desarrollos as $desarrollo)
     <option value="{{ $desarrollo['id_calcu'] }}">{{ $desarrollo['desarrollador'] }}</option>
   @endforeach

    </select>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como cada opción tiene como atributo `value` el id que traes de la base de datos, al enviar `this.value` como parámetro ese es el valor que manda, si quitas el atributo, y lo cambias por `id` entonces te enviará el texto de la opción correctamente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso pasa por que el `.value` te captura el valor que esté en el atributo **value** de tu **option seleccionado** al cual le estás asignando `$desarrollo['id_calcu']`.

Para capturar el texto del **option seleccionado** debes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
function prueba(x){
    var indice = x.selectedIndex;
    var texto = x.options[indice].text;
    var opcion = document.getElementById('inputdesa').value = texto;
}
```

```html
<select onchange="prueba(this);">
    <option value="1">Opción 1</option>
    <option value="2">Opción 2</option>
    <option value="3">Opción 3</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="inputdesa">
```

Answer (score 2):

Fíjate bien en cuando compones el *option*. En valor metes la id, y en el contenido visible el nombre de desarrollador, estas obteniendo el id con tu JS porque recuperas el contenido con **value**.

Necesitas usar **innerHTML**.

Ejemplo:

```
<select>
    <option value="opciones" selected>Elige una opción</option>
    <option id="Uno" value="1">Uno</option>
    <option id="Dos" value="2">Dos</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">

    /**
     * Opción 1
     * Requiere que le añadas una "id" a cada "option" para recuperar su contenido
     *
     */
    var selected_option = document.getElementById( 'Uno' ).innerHTML;
    console.log( selected_option );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que obtener el indice del option selecionado utilizando la propiedad `selectedIndex` del `select` y luego en base al indice accedes a la propiedad `select` del array `options` del `select`  asi:

```js
function mostrarDesarrollador()
{
  var select = document.getElementById("desarrolladores");
  document.getElementById("desarrollador").value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

```html
<select onchange="mostrarDesarrollador()" id="desarrolladores">
  <option value="1">Einer</option>
  <option value="2">Einer 2</option>
  <option value="3">Einer 3</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="desarrollador" />
```

Comment: Hola Einer. Veo que tu respuesta es practicamente igual que la [anteriormente publicada de Camilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/113402/15855).- Supongo que estariais escribiendola a la vez y él la publico antes. Considera eliminarla ya que si no habria contenido duplicado ... y más suerte para la proxima ^^'